# How can I move a set of commits from master to a separate branch?

Tags: git

I have a series of commits (20+) that pertain to a particular feature that I am trying to remove from our master branch and into a separate branch.

I have a tag (`rel_2009_07_18`) on the commit that represents our latest stable release, so when on master, git log `rel_2009_07_18`..HEAD gets me the set of commits that I want to move to a separate branch.  There are also some commits in this set that should remain, but I could just cherry-pick those as they are few.

I've looked at git filter-branch, but the commit option mentions leaving the changes in but removing the commit -- definitely don't want that.  I also looked at git rebase, but that also mentions reapplying the commits to the upstream branch.

Is there a good option for moving these commits to a separate branch?

I'm not sure if this is a viable option and the repercussions in a distributed, albeit small (3 developers), environment.  But could I perform the following little shift...

1. Locally rename the master branch to master_plus_feature (or similar...)
2. Checkout from the `rel_2009_07_18` tag
3. Create a new branch master from this point
4. Delete remote branches and re-push from local

Thoughts and suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You write that you want to **remove** commits from 'master' branch.  This might cause problems if 'master' branch was published (well, commits after `rel_2009_07_18` are published), and somebody based their work on your 'master'.  But perhaps it is not a problem in your case.

Both solutions below assume that you don't have uncomitted changes

#### If you can rewind 'master' branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch separate_branch
$ git reset --hard rel_2009_07_18
```

Now 'master' is at `rel_2009_07_18` tag, and 'separate_branch" is at where 'master' was.  The final result is exactly the same as in set of steps you proposed (rename 'master' to 'separate_branch', recreate 'master' at `rel_2009_07_18`), the only difference is in reflogs.

#### If you can't rewind 'master' branch

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch separate_branch
$ git checkout rel_2009_07_18 -- .
$ git clean -df
$ git commit -m 'Reverted to state at rel_2009_07_18'
```

Note that this solution is not tested!  YMMV.

Comment: I can rewind master, so I'll opt for that solution.  I can notify others of the change.  From there, I can cherry-pick the good commits back into master, right?  That shouldn't cause any real issues down the road with merging separate_branch back into master, right?

Comment: @Eric M. yes, you would be able to cherry-pick into master, and there shouldn't be any issues with merging 'separate\_branch' into 'master' later.

Comment: You can force-push master after rewind even if it was published already with `git push -f`.

Answer (score 9):

For me the easiest option is to use `git-cherry-pick`.

Basically you need to switch to the branch you want the commits on, then using the log of the original branch (`git log master`) you find the SHA-1 of each commit you want and cherry-pick it onto the current branch.

Once this is done, you can then move back to master and reverse all those unwanted commits by using `git-reset` and hey presto, you now have a branch with your new commits, and a clean master branch.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of history being contiguous, create a new branch, then locate the branch you want the original one to be on and update the HEAD:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git log
```

The git log is to locate where the original split should have been.

```
echo {commit id} >.git/refs/heads/original_branch
```

If you checkout original_branch at this point, it'll point at the commit where the new branch should have split.

I personally use this for old repos that I didn't use the git-flow workflow to split the develop and master branches, and I've had no issues with it so far.

If history isn't contiguous, then the same method works except that one has to find the last commit before the branch should have happened, then use cherry-pick to apply the commits that are wanted on original branch.