# Branching with Git and SVN

Tags: git, git-svn

I cloned an SVN repository down and I've been working on master - checking things in locally - but I haven't yet pushed to SVN.

Now, I've decided I want to push my local changes "on master" to a new SVN branch (not to the main trunk).

What is the best way to do that? Should I create a branch in SVN as well as locally on HEAD of master ... and then tie them together? Do I need to identify where either started from etc?

Not sure of the proper set of commands or the proper "Git way" to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your having 2 different issues here.
Move your changes to another branch, and commit a new branch.
About moving the commits form one branch to another follow this thread, [How can I move a set of commits from master to a separate branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178553/how-can-i-move-a-set-of-commits-from-master-to-a-separate-branch)
About how to handle branches in git-svn there is a nice tutorial in: http://www.jukie.net/~bart/blog/svn-branches-in-git

Comment: Great! That worked just fine. One last step - I needed to merge my changes (saved into the alternate branch) into the new svn tracking branch.