# Maven with Git: release from arbitrary commit rather than the HEAD

Tags: git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'd like to do an `mvn release` of an artifact from a past commit; somebody added several commits to the same SNAPSHOT, I'd like those to be excluded and moved over to the next version. Given the following `git log` output:

```
commit ea05
Author: Y

commit 921d
Author: Y

commit 530c
Author: Y

commit 64e9
Author: X
```

I'd like maven to use `64e9` for the release rather than `ea05`

I tried doing `git co 64e9` (detached HEAD), `mvn release:prepare` (worked) and then `mvn release:perform` but it hangs producing the following output:

```
[INFO] Building ABC
[INFO]    task-segment: [release:perform] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [release:perform {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/ABC/target && git clone ssh://repo/ABC.git /home/ABC/target/checkout
[INFO] Working directory: /home/ABC/target
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/ABC/target/checkout && git pull ssh://repo/ABC.git tag ABC-1.6
[INFO] Working directory: /home/ABC/target/checkout
(...hanged)
```

Comment: I would recommend to [undo the changes on the master and than do the release.][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178553/how-can-i-move-a-set-of-commits-from-master-to-a-separate-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@khmarbaise Thanks for inspiration, here's how I ended up solving the problem:

1. Store the current state in a separate branch
2. `git reset --hard` the master to the desired commit
3. `git push --force origin` to avoid "Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by N commits, and can be fast-forwarded."
4. Release using Maven's release plugin
5. Reapply the commits "stashed" in the other branch to the next development version.