# Is there a way to remove commits from one branch and place them into another?

Tags: git

I made a mistake and accidentally was committing to master for a while, and now that I've realized my mistake, I want to move those commit off of the master and back into my own staging branch.

Is this possible, to do with git or am I going to have to manually move files around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a set of commits from master to a separate branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178553/how-can-i-move-a-set-of-commits-from-master-to-a-separate-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mistakes are such that master currently looks like:

```
A->B->C->D
```

and you just want to move `C` and `D` to a new branch, it's pretty easy:

```
$ git checkout master      # move to D
$ git branch new-branch    # create new branch at D
$ git reset B-sha1         # reset master to B
$ git checkout new-branch  # continue working on new-branch
```

Depending on what changes are introduced by `C` and `D`, this may not work cleanly.  For example, if `C` introduces a new file, git may not let you do the checkout of new-branch for fear of overwriting the file.  (When master is checked out at `B`, git thinks the file is untracked.)  You could add a `git clean -xdf` after the reset, or do `reset --hard` depending on the circumstances.

Comment: So what this is doing is moving things to a different branch, and development continues there? Does this allow me to salvage the remote master as well?

Comment: @Alex  If you have already pushed to a remote, you have more work to do.  If you know that no one else has pulled from that remote, you can do an update-ref there, but if you cannot guarantee that you will need to add some `revert` commits.  If you a

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you made 5 commits to master by mistake, move the commits:

```
git checkout master
git branch temp
git rebase --onto yourbranch temp~5 temp
```

Update the branches:

```
git push . temp:yourbranch
git push . master~5:master -f
```

Update your remote master:

```
git push origin master -f
```

Tell your colleagues what you did so they can adjust their master according to your correction.